# What happened to llseek and e2fsck?

Tags: linux, system-calls, glibc

[lseek man page:](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lseek64.3.html)

> When users complained about data loss caused by a
> miscompilation of e2fsck(8), glibc 2.1.3 added the link-time
> warning
>
> > "the `llseek` function may be dangerous; use `lseek64
> > instead."
>
> This makes this function unusable if one desires a warning-free
> compilation.
>
> Since glibc 2.28, this function symbol is no longer available to
> newly linked applications.

What's the story behind this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that glibc included a `llseek` symbol, with no corresponding declaration in its header files. `e2fsck`’s configuration script detected the symbol, and assumed that meant the function was usable. However, the implicit function declaration didn’t match what the function expected, and the function call ended up being miscompiled as a result. In particular, `llseek` expects a 64-bit offset, but the implicit declaration results in `int` arguments — this is what caused data loss, since `e2fsck` made changes at different offsets than what it expected.

The reason `e2fsck` used `llseek` is that libc5, glibc’s predecessor on Linux, declared it and made it usable (it was in `unistd.h`). So `e2fsck`, when built against libc5, correctly used `llseek`; but when built against glibc, built successfully but failed to work correctly.

This was fixed in e2fsprogs 1.12, with the following changelog entry:

> E2fsprogs now works with glibc (at least with the version shipped with
> RedHat 5.0).  The ext2fs_llseek() function should now work even with
> i386 ELF shared libraries and if llseek() is not present.  We also
> explicitly do a configure test to see if (a) llseek is in libc, and
> (b) if llseek is declared in the system header files.  (See standard
> complaints about libc developers don't understand the concept of
> compatibility with previous versions of libc.)

The C library was also changed to issue a warning if code tried to use `llseek`; [the discussion can be found in the mailing list archives](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-alpha/1999-November/001617.html).

Comment: Are all symbols not declared by glibc considered unsafe to use? What makes llseek "may be dangers" except the absence  of a declaration (which makes it prone to mis-compilation?)

Comment: The problem with `llseek` specifically is that it was available in libc5, declared in `unistd.h`. Thus code which tried to use it worked in libc5, and did the wrong thing in libc6.

Comment: So the implicit declaration assumes this function returns int, which `llseek` clearly doesn't, hence the program would mis-compile(return type mismatch). So `llseek` isn't inherently dangerous, but the implicit declaration is.

Comment: The implicit declaration assumes that all arguments are `int`, but the offset is a 64-bit type; so the caller thinks it’s seeking to a given offset, but the value passed to.the function is different. That’s what caused data loss. Your conclusion is correct, it’s the implicit declaration that’s dangerous.